# Why do I get a NullReferenceException when attempting to upload a file to ADLS?

Tags: c#, azure

I'm using the following code to upload a test file to the ADLS. I keep getting a null reference error but I can't figure out what is null and what is being referenced. I keep trying to comment out parts of the line to find out at what point it becomes null with no success.

```
var creds = new ClientCredential(CLIENTID, CLIENTSECRET);
            var clientCreds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(TENANT, creds).Result;
            using (DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient adlsFileSystemClient = new DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient(clientCreds))
            {
                var g = adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.UploadFile(_adlsAccountName, "test.txt", "/test.txt", threadCount: 1, resume: false, overwrite: false);
            }
```

Comment: Add a language tag to your question. If you're in Visual Studio you should be able to debug and hover of each variable to determine which is Nothing.

Comment: Ok thanks, I added the tag. I will try the hover thing.

Comment: You should be able to tell from the exception which line it occurred on, and include that information in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please post full exception details.